# execute db2 pl sql functions returning cursor from python

Tags: python, db2

I have pl sql package containing a function that returns a ref_cursor object.

Following is my python code, in which I am trying to call that function

```
temp=""
con = get_connection()  //get connection will return connection object
sql = 'values function_name(?)'
stmt = ibm_db.prepare(con, sql)
ibm_db.bind_param(stmt, 1, temp, ibm_db.SQL_PARAM_OUTPUT)
ibm_db.execute(stmt)
```

While executing this python code I am getting following error:

```
Statement Execute Failed: [IBM][CLI Driver][DB2/LINUXX8664] SQL20441N  A "CURSOR" data type is not supported in the context where it is being used.  SQLSTATE=428H2 SQLCODE=-20441
```

How can I execute this function from python and get read this cursor variable?

Edit:

Actually I am trying to migrate my Oracle database to DB2.
In Oracle I have a PL/SQL package containing function which is returning a sys_refcursor object.

```
FUNCTION my_function(l_parameter IN NUMBER) RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR IS
        l_sql1 VARCHAR2(4000):= Select query1;
        l_sql2 VARCHAR2(4000):= Select query2;
        r_refcursor SYS_REFCURSOR;
    BEGIN
        IF l_parameter = 1 THEN
            OPEN r_refcursor for l_sql1;
        ElSE
            OPEN r_refcursor for l_sql2;
        END IF;
    RETURN r_refcursor;
END my_function;
```

Do we need to modify the function?
How can I call this function from db2 as well as from python?

Comment: Functions with OUT or INOUT parameters can only be invoked in PL/SQL contexts.

Comment: Hi @mustaccio
I have a function in PL/SQL package which is returning a ref cursor object.

I tried executing the function as follows:
select function_name() from dual;

But still got the same error message.

Can you please give some example?

Comment: Again, `sys_refcursor` data type is not valid in the SQL context. It's unclear what you are trying to achieve, but consider using a table function instead.

Comment: Hi @mustaccio
I have modified the question.
The package containing the function got compiled and I can see the function in IBM Data studio.
Do I need to modify the function?
Can you give me some example for calling this function from IBM Data studio?